# Better way to retopo?

Tags: loop

I want to pass a couple edge loops through the abdomen, but as you can see, the edge loops pass all the way around the side, up the back, neck, head, and down the front.

I've been practicing retopology and have been trying to make really clean topo.  It seems like I'm TOO interconnected.  What did I do wrong here?

Don't hold back!

.blend at http://www.filedropper.com/retopopractice1

[image: Retopology Practice]

Comment: Hi. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) if you want to provide files for us to check. Random file sharing services won't keep them up long enough.

Comment: @metaphor Unfortunately, this file is 61 megs.  Likely due to the density of the model.  I believe blend-exchange has a 30 meg limit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topology of the back is bad, it makes the edge loops come back vertically, so you need to create some vertical edge loops with the knife, delete the oblique edges, make sure it only leaves quads, then horizontal edge loops will be possible:

[image]